# What fonts are these?

Tags: fonts

I have a problem identifying what fonts are used in typesetting these pdf documents. However, since I'm a beginner here with low reputation, I can't post an image caption of the files. Even if I could do so, the quality of the image is so low that I'm afraid won't be clear enough in order to identify the fonts correctly. So I managed to upload two examples pdf files in Dropbox and put the links here. I'm sorry if that may cause you any difficulty.

For the first font, the letters look almost the same as the default font of Latex typesetting. However there's a small difference. You can view it in the sample file [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/stnyscuvdpkwawe/Font1.pdf). For the second, the letters are slightly fatter. You can view it [here](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9ndtmnsr3xrlgca/Font2.pdf).

Any help is greatly appreciated. I really don't know who to ask, because I just encountered the pdf files, not the .tex files, and had no idea what fonts are used.

Comment: Right click on the pdf files and look at the document properties the fonts are listed there. Otherwise you can upload them to [Whatthefont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but unfortunately these are off-topic questions here.

Comment: see any of the duplicate questions that are automatically linked in the "related" list on the right of this page. Acrobat's font meny (or the pdffonts command line tool) will tell you all the fonts in a pdf document

Comment: Those *are* the default fonts for LaTeX. The first is Latin Modern, the second Computer Modern (plus some).

Comment: Well, perhaps I haven't made it clear enough. What I actually want to know is: what should I do, when typing tex document, in order that the fonts I desire appear in my pdf files? Is there any special package or something I must declare in order that latex would produce the font I desire? For example, @mafp said that these are default fonts. But I have typed many tex documents and the fonts I desire never appear in my resulting pdf files. I checked the document property of my pdf files, seeing many fonts indicated there. Still, I have no idea how I can make use of them. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Without loading any package you get the Computer Modern font as in your second link. For Latin Modern you add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Really appreciate that, @mafp.